PBI Table Reference - power query Exporting a PBI table to a power query
Good afternoon!
In the table in power bi, I created new columns and so on, But there are no such columns in power query, how can I output the calculated columns created in power query?
I tried to combine queries in power query, update the table, but the created calculated columns did not appear there

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

What's the point?
I'm just trying to unload the modified excel table from the pbi
